# How to speed up queries on non indexed columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of error logs with around 300 million rows. There is an index on the Date column but I am trying to query by both date and error message. When I query by date it is fast but I need to query by message as well which slows it down.

My query is as follows

```
WITH data_cte(errorhour, message) 
     AS (SELECT Datepart(hh, date) AS ErrorDay, 
                message 
         FROM   cloud.errorlog 
         WHERE  date <= '2016-06-02' 
           AND  date >= '2016-06-01') 
SELECT errorhour, 
       Count(*) AS count, 
       message 
FROM   data_cte 
WHERE  message = 'error connecting to the server' 
GROUP  BY errorhour 
ORDER  BY errorhour
```

adding the where clause slows it down because Message is not indexed. How can I speed it up?

**EDIT:** I cannot index on `Message` because it is defined as `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Add an index maybe?

Comment: I can't add an index because it is varchar(max)

Comment: @user3491649 So why you can't add index to varchar(max) ?

Comment: 900bytes isn't much.  True.

Comment: It's possible that your table statistics are messed up and adding the message condition is making the database not use the index at all.  Check the query plan with the message condition and make sure your table statistics are up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will **ALWAYS** be searching for the text `'error connecting to the server'` then you can use a *filtered* index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ectts ON ErrorLog (Date) 
   WHERE (Date between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-02')
     AND Message='error connecting to the server';
```

This index should be fairly small in bytes consumed, and quick to consult.
It may be fairly slow to update however; consider creating it every time you need to run this query and dropping it afterward.

Another choice is to [use a computed column on the first few hundred characters of `Message`, and index on that](https://explainextended.com/2009/05/01/indexing-varcharmax/):

```
ALTER TABLE ErrorLog
   ADD Message_index AS (cast (Message as varchar(400)));

CREATE INDEX theIndex ON ErrorLog (Message_index, [date]);
```

EDIT: added missing parentheses after cast

Comment: is the cast correct? for some reason i am getting a syntax error:

Comment: ^ check out the above comments

Comment: if you get rid of the top solution and leave the second one you posted I will give you the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Just create a composite index for `(date, message)` and filter on the internal cte, not outside.

```
WITH data_cte(errorhour, message) 
     AS (SELECT Datepart(hh, date) AS ErrorDay, 
                message 
         FROM   cloud.errorlog 
         WHERE  date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-02'
           AND  message = 'error connecting to the server'
         )
```

Comment: The problem is I can't create a index for Message because it is varchar(max)

Comment: @RossPresser really, please go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post a link to a working example.

Comment: @RossPresser So you cant create the index?

Comment: You were correct, Juan, an index cannot be created on a `varchar(max)` column. I have deleted my incorrect comment that indicated otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query to:

```
     SELECT Datepart(day, date) AS ErrorDay, datepart(hour, date) as ErrorHour
            count(*) 
     FROM cloud.errorlog 
     WHERE date <= '2016-06-02' AND  date >= '2016-06-01') AND
           message = 'error connecting to the server'
     GROUP BY Datepart(day, date), datepart(hour, date);
```

Then for this query, you want an index on `errorlog(message, date)`.  It is important that the `message` be first in the index, because of the equality comparison.

EDIT:

If the message is too long and you want queries like this, I would recommend adding a computed column and use that for the index and `where` clause:

```
alter table errlog add message250 as (left(message, 250));

create index idx_errlog_message250_date on (message250, date);
```

And then write the query as:

```
     SELECT Datepart(day, date) AS ErrorDay, datepart(hour, date) as ErrorHour
            count(*) 
     FROM cloud.errorlog 
     WHERE date <= '2016-06-02' AND  date >= '2016-06-01') AND
           message250 = 'error connecting to the server'
     GROUP BY Datepart(day, date), datepart(hour, date);
```

Comment: I can't add index because Message is varchar max

Comment: really the order matter? isnt the planner smart enough yet?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Yes, the ordering matters.  Otherwise I would have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to extract a short summary of the error message, you could then include that in the INSERT to the log into a new column say `error_summary` and you could index on that and use it in the SELECT.

You'd parse the full error message and strip out timestamps, userid's and specifics such as server name and maybe stack traces. If there is no clear parsing, leave `error_summary` as `null`. You could then do a preliminary search on `error_summary` and fall back to a search on `Message` if that failed.

Comment: This is equivalent in function to using a computed column and indexing it

Comment: That's true if you know the start position of the error text you're looking for inside `Message`, The OP is using `varchar(max)` so it suggests the whole message could be pretty big. He doesn't say how it's formatted, so it would be useful if the OP could post some examples of what is in `Message`, with just the first 100 bytes or so of each row.

Comment: His original query asked for equality to a short string: `WHERE  message = 'error connecting to the server' `

Comment: @JohnD the message is of variable length and each error has a different message so the message could take up all of the varchar max or only some of it

Comment: Does the error you're interested in always start at the beginning of the string? If so, then you could try what the other answers suggest. I.e. add a computed column to your table such as `substring(Message, 1, 100)` and then create an index on that.

Comment: No I am interested in finding all errors for a particular date range not just one error that starts with the same string. All of the errors have different messages.